# Determine typescript property union from generic argument type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have some kinds of filter operations

```
type FilterOp = 'Equals' | 'NotEquals' | 'Greater' | 'GreaterEqual' | 'Less' | 'LessEqual';
type ArrayFilterOp = 'In' | 'NotIn';
type StringFilterOp = 'StartsWith' | 'EndsWith' | 'Contains' | 'NotContains';
type DateFilterOp = 'DateIn' | 'DateNotIn'
```

and this is my current filter definition

```
type GenericFilter<T> = {
    Property: string,
    Value: T,
    Operation: FilterOp | ArrayFilterOp | StringFilterOp | DateFilterOp
}
```

Is it possible to somehow determine `Operation` type based upon `T` argument? For example if my `T` is `Date` then typescript would allow only `DateFilterOp` and `FilterOp` assignment to `Operation` property

```
let dateFilter: GenericFilter<Date> = {
    Property: "DateCreated",
    Value: new Date(),
    Operation: // now I can only set value from FilterOp or DateFilterOp
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand the constraint correctly, you could use [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) to represent it:

```
type Operation<T> =
  | FilterOp
  | (T extends Array<any> ? ArrayFilterOp : never)
  | (T extends string ? StringFilterOp : never)
  | (T extends Date ? DateFilterOp : never);

type GenericFilter<T> = {
  Property: string;
  Value: T;
  Operation: Operation<T>;
};
```

This will support your stated use case:

```
let dateFilter: GenericFilter<Date> = {
  Property: "DateCreated",
  Value: new Date(),
  Operation: "DateIn"
};
```

as well as work with a helper function so you can just *infer* `T` instead of specifying it manually:

```
const asGenericFilter = <T>(filt: GenericFilter<T>) => filt;

let stringFilter = asGenericFilter({
  Property: "Name",
  Value: "Alice",
  Operation: "StartsWith" // hinted as Operation<string>
})
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgeTFAvAKClAHygCIBRARwFcBDBAZ2L0JIDkB7YCm+x-I4gOIoI1ZCl7NBw0ai60J-ADIQ6DJkpV05CYgG4coSFACCKFNRDwkqDNhIBJAHbFJ7YE70Hw0AMrAUcI4A5lZitlgkftQowHQA6nDAABYu-KSOACbxiSmSAMJsjsDUgQyuHAVFJY4M+obQACIyoTaYEcRNyB6SnRBuHvpeRhioonCFADwAKgB82OqwiGFgCwAUU1AQAB7ImXQmZhYT1I4gcwD8B+aWS61QAFxQjhAAbqgAlGsb27tZUHT+QJBKCXPwBYItdCYR7PN4oT58KDrTY7CB7KC9EEY5q3KEPJ6vD6DepQARo1BwADGkOmcwiAG8mAAFFBsSAxECPAHgoL6fAANVolAgjymfKgI3MwHGjkekrGk1m+gAvoMEBBgFAMjjrChHmTngFqbiJr06VBGfgWWzUKBHh0ZHlpMgMsQADRMQUIYUwiAAd2xyFW7w9+Hl0sK9t6HhwqpwOEphQBUGodANFONurstNWADMlvryUaabN3tg5vmkGqNf9ARDcXZU+ni7jVpaoNb2XbWNQALYQd2eoUikjGBBUgehiXshWyyLFGLZZIuWPvIA)

Comment: Yeah, I've implemented something similar, but your is a bit cleaner, thanks on effort!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to implement solution through `OperationMap`

```
type OperationMap<T> = 
    T extends Date
        ? (DateFilterOp | FilterOp)
        : T extends Array<any>
            ? ArrayFilterOp
            : T extends String
                ? FilterOp | StringFilterOp
    : FilterOp;

type GenericFilter<T> = {
    Property: string,
    Value: T,
    Operation: OperationMap<T>
}
```